# i m using krajee plugin to upload multiple images using ajax but when i try to upload extra data

Tags: ajax, laravel, ajaxform

> i m using krajee plugin to upload multiple images using ajax but when
>   i try to upload extra data with it so save the extra data according to
>   the number of the multiple images like if the images are three so user
>   name is also saved three times.
>    **the code is below**

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $("#image").fileinput({
        uploadUrl: "{{route('saveUser')}}", // server upload action
        uploadAsync: true,
        minFileCount: 1,
        maxFileCount: 50,
        overwriteInitial: true,
        data: {'_token': "{{csrf_token()}}"},
        initialPreviewAsData: true, // identify if you are sending preview data only and not the raw markup
        initialPreviewFileType: 'image', // image is the default and can be overridden in config below
        initialPreviewConfig: [
            {caption: "People-1.jpg", size: 576237, width: "120px", url: "/site/file-delete", key: 1},
            {caption: "People-2.jpg", size: 932882, width: "120px", url: "/site/file-delete", key: 2},
        ],
        uploadExtraData: function() {
            return {
//                img_key: "1000",
//                img_keywords: "happy, places",
                cycle: $("#cycle").val(),
                description: $("#description").val()
//                user_id: $("#user_id").val()

            };
        }
    });


</script>
```